# element not interactable error in selenium using node js and angular js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

`element not interactable` I get this error when I run a test case. the element is a button. What could be the possible reason? Here`s the code inside "it".

```
this.timeout(85000);
        browser
            .pause(global.BROWSERPAUSEVALUE)
            .element('[data-short-description="solicitation-signin-email"]')
            .setValue('xyz@rmail.com')
            .pause(global.BROWSERPAUSEVALUE)
            .click('[data-btn="user-signin"]')
            .click('[data-btn="user-signin"]')
            .notify(done);
```

Comment: node js, not in java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element is not interactable yet.Try setting an implicit wait while initializing the driver:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: @Noob , Sorry for the mistake. Did you try to use implicity wait ??